# Checking bounce rate on auth dialog

Tags: facebook, authentication, dialog, analytics

I know there used to be a way to check the bounce rate of users who opened the Auth dialog on a website with Facebook Connect and then canceled without authorizing. This seems to have moved from the App Insights. Is this still available, and if so, where can one find it?

Comment: Insights -> Users -> Growth? (not sure about the last one, „Wachstum“ in German, but that means growth)

Comment: @CBroe If you have access to a dashboard, maybe post a quick screen shot or add your comment as an answer (just to make it easier for other people to find)?

Comment: Good suggestion, Ricardo! Done that (and switched my FB language to English first, so that it is probably more useful for the majority of users).

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on how many users clicked through your Auth dialog in the app dashboard under *Insights -> Users -> Growth*, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of app dashboard showing Insights -> Users -> Growth panel]

There you can also see which kind of permissions combinations where asked for and accepted by how many users – it has stats for Impressions total, CTR, Total Accepts (further down the page, not shown in screenshot).